# How do I save the changes to my vim buffer as a patch file?

Tags: vim, diff

Is there a way to save the changes I made to my vim buffer as a patch file for the original file, without saving it as a separate file and using diff?

Comment: There's a new SE beta site for [Vi and Vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/), you might want to check it out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's possible to do this without a plugin using the `w` command, so the buffer contents can be used in a shell command:

```
:w !diff -au "%" - > changes.patch
```

(`%` is substituted with the path of the file being edited, `-` reads the buffer from stdin)

Comment: You can use `diff -u "%" -` since `diff` understands a dash as meaning _read from stdin_

Answer (score 1):

You could also filter the buffer through `diff` using the `%!` syntax:

```
:%! diff -au "%" -
```

This will fill the buffer with the diff, rather than writing it to disk; you may want to set `readonly` so you don't clobber the original by accident (OTOH, that shouldn't be a serious problem because you have the file under version control, *right?*).  Of course, it helps to have the inverse command:

```
:%! patch -o - "%"
```

That transforms your diff back into the modified file.